# Why was Gaia in deep slumber during creation?

Tags: greek, titans, giants

In all of Greek mythology, [Gaia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia) played an important role: giving birth to the titans and giants, etc.

But most of the time she is in a deep slumber in the creation of mythology?

Why?

Comment: Could you add some references as to why you state she is mostly in deep slumber? Main sources such as Hesiod do not include this notion.